# Add several css property by parsing the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to add some css in some div.

My Html:

```
<div class="data-item">
    <a class="title" id="cms-occasion" style="font-size: 14px !important;" href="#">Cadeau pour un diplômé</a>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="data-item">
    <a class="title" id="cms-occasion" style="font-size: 14px !important;" href="#">Cadeau Stage pilotage</a>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="data-item">
    <a class="title" id="cms-occasion" style="font-size: 14px !important;" href="#">Idees cadeaux</a>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

My Js function which is wrong:

```
var giftIdea = document.getElementById('cms-occasion').innerHTML.indexOf('Idees cadeaux');
if (giftIdea != -1){
    giftIdea.style.display = 'block';
    giftIdea.style.width = '100%';
    giftIdea.style.bottom = '-117px';
    giftIdea.style.text-align = 'left';
    giftIdea.style.position = 'absolute';
    giftIdea.style.background-color = '#535353';
    giftIdea.style.padding = '6px';

}
```

Can someone tell what's wrong on my JS function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IDs are unique and should only be used once per page.

Comment: Instead of using IDs you should use classes if you want to access multiple elements

Comment: Also in your JS `giftIdea` isn't an element anymore, it's a number, since you put `.innerHTML.indexOf('Idees cadeaux')` after retrieving the element by ID. (But also, first and foremost, what Johannes said: IDs must be unique)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an important rule in HTML that you seem to ignore : you can not have several elements with the same ID. An ID is a unique identifier.

Likewise, JS `getElementById` will return only one element.
Your selector return the first element and then search for the position of the string you pass to `indexOf`.

Try using `class` instead of `ID` and target them with `document.querySelectorAll`.
You can filter the returned array like this

`document.querySelectorAll('.cms-occasion').filter(function(el){ return el.innerHTML.indexOf('Idees cadeaux') !== -1 })`